# Class mocking in Django tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using mock 1.0.1 (http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to mock objects in my tests, and I'm able to mock dates using this approach:

```
def dateStub():
    return timezone.make_aware(datetime(2013, 1, 1, 10, 30), timezone.utc)


@patch('django.utils.timezone.now', dateStub)
def testFoo(self):
    ...
```

But, now I'm trying to mock a class and the same approach is not working as expected:

```
class FakeClass(OriginalClass)
    def method(self):
        pass


@patch('myapp.mymodule.OriginalClass', FakeClass)
def testFoo(self):
    ...
```

I also tried using @path.object and replacing only the class method, but with no luck... what is the right way to mocking a class in a test? (the class is used internally by the class that I'm testing)

Comment: Could you include the code that uses `OriginalClass`? Is `OriginalClass` imported from another module or is it defined in `myapp.mymodule`?

Comment: the class OriginalClass is defined in myapp.mymodule.OriginalClass and in my test I use another class that imports it... in practice I have: TestClassA (the test class) with the testFoo() method and inside it ClassA() which in the method "method" uses OriginalClass (which lives in a separate module)

Comment: That wouldn't mock the class. You need to ensure you mock the OriginalClass at the place where it's instantiated in the real code. Is OriginalClass perhaps instantiated in that seperate module and stored in a global variable?

Comment: OriginalClass is imported in other modules using: "from myapp.mymodule.OriginalClass import OriginalClass", even django.utils.timezone is imported in the same way in other classes and is patchable ...why?

Comment: The difference is that `now()` is a function that you're mocking but calling `OriginalClass()` means you're instantiating an instance so you sometimes need to mock `OriginalClass.return_value` instead. See: http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#mocking-classes

Comment: Finally I solved!!!! Check my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

I solved!

The working solution is the following:

```
...
from myapp.mymodule.OriginalClass import OriginalClass

def methodStub(self):
    return

class TestMyClass(TestCase):

    @patch.object(OriginalClass, 'method', methodStub)
    def testFoo(self):
        ...
```